# How to make checkbox checked by default in magento system cinfiguration (Custom Module)

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, admin-panel

I have been working on custom module, It flows like when user comes in

`Admin -> System -> Configuration -> My Module`

There is a **checkbox** and its value is **TERMS & CONDITIONS**, So when page loads that **checkbox have to be checked by default**

Can anybody help ?

Comment: Is it frontend or backend please make it clear

Comment: @Kothari Obviously its Backend. in System Configuration

Comment: Can you please show me your full code of this